# Intraweb+Delphi: Installing multiple instances of the service

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, intraweb

Before I spend what is sure to be many hours tracking down a problem, I wanted to find out if anyone else has successfully installed the **same Intraweb service multiple times on the same server** (running on different ports, of course!), and if you had to do something strange to get it going or if I might have done something strange to prevent it. :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to make ServerController.AppName configurable via an INI file or so. Thats the name Window's service manager will take as unique identifier for the service when you run it with /install.
ServerController.Port should also be read from an INI file of course.

Using that techinique I am running multiple IW services (of the same appp) on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks Olaf, that's just what I needed to know. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Worked a charm. Just out of curiosity, when do you read from the INI file and set the ServerController.AppName? Override Create? Or an event? There doesn't seem to be a clear time to do it.